# update the UI of fragment from onPostExecute called from onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

In my application I launch an intent with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on a button click to pick a document.

```
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
public void performFileSearch() {

    // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
    // browser.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = {
            "image/*",
            "text/plain",
            "application/pdf"
    };
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

After that, I fetch the `Uri` of the document selected by the user in `onActivityResult` and pass it on to an `AsyncTask` where the selected document is zipped.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.upload_dialog));
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

            // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
            // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
            // provided to this method as a parameter.
            // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
            new ZipFile().execute(data.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my `AsyncTask` class:

```
private class ZipFile extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
        Uri uri = uris[0];
        String fileName = null;

        try {
            fileName = zm.createPath("user");
            zm.zipFromUri(uri, fileName, commonMethods.getFileName(uri));
        } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String fileName) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (fileName != null) {
            renderView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `renderView` function, I display a snackbar and update the UI of my fragment.

```
private void renderView(View view) {

    CoordinatorLayout fileSnackbarView = view.findViewById(R.id.filesCoordinatorLayout);

    //Exception at this line
    fileSnackbar = Snackbar.make(fileSnackbarView, String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.snackbarMessage), FILE_COUNT), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.snackbarAction), new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewSelectedFilesActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    ArrayList<String> selectedFileName = new ArrayList<>();
                    selectedFileName.add(commonMethods.getFromPreferences(Constants.originalFileNameKey, "string"));
                    bundle.putStringArrayList("fileList", selectedFileName);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    ... code        
}
```

However, my application crashes with the exception `Fragment not attached to a context`. Below is the complete stack trace:

```
03-08 12:09:20.647 11490-11490/com.zeetim.zeeprintmobile.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.zeetim.zeeprintmobile.android, PID: 11490
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{674af0} not attached to a context.
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:611)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:675)
    at com.zeetim.zeeprintmobile.fragment.HomeFragment.renderView(HomeFragment.java:287)
    at com.zeetim.zeeprintmobile.fragment.HomeFragment.access$700(HomeFragment.java:51)
    at com.zeetim.zeeprintmobile.fragment.HomeFragment$ZipFile.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:595)
    at com.zeetim.zeeprintmobile.fragment.HomeFragment$ZipFile.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:563)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

On some debugging, I found that `isAdded()` returns `false` and  `getActivity()`, `getContext()` are `null`.

The flow seems very straight forward, but it's not working. So is there anything that I am missing in this?
How can I update the UI of my fragment from `onPostExecute` which is called from `onActivityResult`?

Thank you.

Comment: Any chances `Activity` get destroyed and recreated ? Have you check this behavior in multiple devices ? If not then try to check it some other device too .

Comment: @ADM It's the same behaviour on other device as well. Concerning the activity, I can see that `onResume` is called after `onActivityResult`. But I am not sure whether the `AsyncTask` class has reference to the new activity or not.

Comment: Show your renderView() code please. remove all statements and then add them one by one to see which statement causes the problem.

Comment: @greenapps I have updated the question with the renderView method

Comment: Yes i saw that later. Why did not you tell rigth away!? `String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.snackbarMessage)`. The statement that causes the problem is much to complicated with two of such parameters. Take that code out and do it before you call that line. Find out what exactly causes your prolem. It looks like a resource problem.

Comment: Maybe you should try something like getContext().getResources().

Comment: @greenapps Yes, I already know that it's the resource issue. `getContext()` is returning null, and I am trying to figure out the reason behind that.

Comment: Well you could demomonstrate your problem then with less code in renderView() by only calling getResource(). Why bother us with the rest?

Comment: `In my application I launch an intent` Are you doing that from a `Fragment` ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. All the above mentioned code is in the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `onPostExecute`

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           //if(isAdded()) {
            if (fileName != null) {
                renderView(view);
            }
         }

       // }
    },300);
```

Comment: No. It's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

A hack of sorts:

Since your code passes this:

`CoordinatorLayout fileSnackbarView = view.findViewById(R.id.filesCoordinatorLayout);`

you can use view to access resources:

`view.getContext().getResources()` instead of `getResources()`

---

The real issue is that your HomeFragment lost contact with the Activity.

I don't think the error is in the code you provided. More likely:

- something wrong happens to your activity (although I doubt it)
- something wrong happens to your fragment (more like it)

It may be that during the `doInBackground` another part of your code replaces your fragment with another, or removes it.